# CSS list items in triangle shape from top to bottom

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make css-based highscores.
What I basically want, is a triangle shape with list-items.
like so:

```
   1
 2 3 4
5 6 7 8 9
```

I tried several methods to center my elements, but I just can't get it to work.
When I position the elements absolutely, they are layered on top of each other.
Margin-left: 10% and margin-right:10% aren't working either, it's just changing margins 
between the list item elements.
I've included a jsfiddle, so you can take a look at it:

http://jsfiddle.net/us454/

hopefully someone can help me out!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411215/creating-a-pyramid-using-css-and-js Couple of good solutions on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possible solution. Either way. Do not style the UL for that reason. Better use the list items:

http://jsfiddle.net/y3p8f/

```
ul.triangle
{
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;   
}

ul.triangle li
{
    border-radius:50px;
    background-color:black;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="triangle">
    <li></li>
</ul>

<ul class="triangle">
    <li></li>
     <li></li>
</ul>
....
```

Update:

here is a slightly more clean version: http://jsfiddle.net/y3p8f/2/

This appends all items into one UL

```
ul.triangle,
ul.triangle li
{
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;   
}

ul.triangle > li
{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;   
}

ul.triangle > li > ul li
{
    border-radius:50px;
    background-color:black;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: really awesome ! keep up

Comment: Thank you @CodingAnt i guess it's a bit ugly to repeat the uls.. The best way would be to add this in one element. I'll try to update it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use div and text align to center the content

See this example

http://jsfiddle.net/4gUrZ/

```
div { text-align:center; }
```